# Warning about making pointer from integer without a cast -- explanation needed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, casting, int

I have this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath");

    //The hud will dispable all input on the view
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];

    // Add HUD to screen
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];

    // Regisete for HUD callbacks so we can remove it from the window at the right time
    HUD.delegate = self;

    HUD.labelText = @"Loading Events, Please Wait..";

    int i = indexPath.row;

    //Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadData:) onTarget:self withObject:i animated:YES];   
}
```

And I get this warning:

> warning: passing argument 3 of 'showWhileExecuting:onTarget:withObject:animated:' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Can somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong here?  Could someone also briefly explain the situation with ints in Objective-C, coming from Java I find it odd that they are so confusing to use.

Comment: Actually the situation of ints in Java it's exactly the same as in Objective-C :) sometimes you need to "box" them in NSNumber to pass it around. The parameter name "withObject:" tells you that you require an NSObject or an id parameter there, not a simple int. Just create an NSNumber with your int, and pass it to your method.

Comment: Also consider [`UIActivityIndicatorView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html)for an Apple-supported official class you could use instead of `MBProgressHUD`.

Comment: Java does [autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), that's why this will magically work in Java. Objective-C does not. You need to be explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `showWhileExecuting:onTarget:withObject:animated:` takes an object as its third argument. To get aroung this, you can wrap integers as objects using the NSNumber class

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]
```

You will then have to unwrap the argument in the `loadData:` method by calling

```
[argument intValue]
```

Answer (score 2):

The method takes an object as a third argument (`withObject`), but you passed an `int` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you provided an integer(int i) instead of an object pointer(type of id). It is not safe. Use NSNumber instead.

```
int i;
...
NSNumber * numberI = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];

[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadData:) onTarget:self withObject:i animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers above are the "correct" ones.  I.e. be a good boy and use and NSNumber to pass the value.

However, … the following will work

"damn you, compiler, i'm smarter than you are:"
(cast your integer, totally not a valid object, to `id`)

```
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadData:) 
                   onTarget:self 
                 withObject:(id)i 
                   animated:YES];
```

i'm guessing (you didn't say), that your load data method looked like this:

```
- (void)loadData:(int)i { …
```

you *will* see code like this, which is the only reason i mentioned it.
you should be familiar with it.
someone thinks that saving 1 object allocation is going to make their code efficient; don't sweat object allocations, and wrap it up in an NSNumber as shown above

most C compilers will handle this correctly, but it's not guaranteed

Comment: If you're definition of "work" is "crashes often", that'll work.  And if you ever see code that that casts non-object types to object types and back again, consider firing the coder who wrote it.  Seriously;  it'll lead to crashes -- something will try to retain (or retain/autorelease) the "object" and **boom**.